# Do not hide number when calling friends?

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts

A friend has an iPhone 4 or 5 running iOS 7, and has configured her phone to always hide her number when making calls, as a safety measure.

As a result, I can't tell it's her calling, since all her calls says "Private number".

Is it possible to configure an iPhone to hide its number for all out calls *except* for such and such person in the phone's list of contacts?

Comment: Why can't you just answer the phone?

Comment: @user3439894 personally I don't answer blocked calls either, 99.99% are spam.

Comment: That's why. I got better things to do.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly.

Your mileage may vary, as this is a carrier dependent function.  I was however able to achieve the following using two AT&T phones in the U.S.

First I opened Settings > Phone > Show my Caller ID and turned the switch off.

Next I placed a test call to the second phone, the other phone correctly displayed "no caller id".   (Note: it does NOT matter who the carrier is for the second phone, all the magic relates to what the first phones carrier offers.)

Next I google "AT&T star codes" and located [this](http://www.vaughns-1-pagers.com/telecom/star-codes-guide.htm) list.  *82 looked like the best choice.

I then modified the contact for the second phone, adding *82 before the phone number.

Calling that contact then allowed my caller id info to be displayed on the second phone, while still being blocked for others.

It's my understanding that *82 is reasonably standard for the code itself in the U.S.  I have no idea which carriers support it however (other than AT&T where I did test).  I also have no idea what carriers in other countries might use, or if it's supported with a star code.  Consult Google for "(carrier name) star codes" or check with the carrier.

Comment: Thanks. I'll ask whether her carrier here in Europe supports that feature. Too bad Apple doesn't support it in its OS.

Comment: Apple could add to support such a feature for a better user experience, but the underlying technology has to be provided at the carrier level.  It's beyond what Apple alone can provide.

Comment: Her carrier doesn't suppor the *82 code.

And prepending #31# manually before each occasional call she wants to make anonymously… is a bit cumbersome :-/

Comment: You might check [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caller_ID) Wikipedia article that lists unblock codes in a list of countries.. See the section titled "getting around caller ID" and scroll to the "enabling" title.

Answer (score 0):

No, but you could ask Apple to do that feature for you/us in the future at http://apple.com/feedback

In the mean time, have her send you an iMessage before calling so you know to answer.